# Nginx, spring boot hello world and example.com

Tags: spring-boot, nginx

Based on this guide:

https://clouding.io/hc/en-us/articles/360010806999-How-to-Deploy-Spring-Boot-Application-with-Nginx-on-Ubuntu-18-04

I have installed nginx and started the spring boot hello world application. But when I access example.com in my browser it just shows:

[image]

If I instead access it directly at:

http://localhost:8080/

```
Hello world
```

it works.

What am I missing?

Details:

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/helloworld.conf**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name example.com;

        location / {
             proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        }
}
```

**/etc/systemd/system/helloworld.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Spring Boot HelloWorld
After=syslog.target
After=network.target[Service]
User=root
Type=simple

[Service]

ExecStart=/home/user/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.10-open/bin/java -jar /home/user/repos/hello-world/build/libs/hello-world-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=helloworld

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And the application is running:

```
$ sudo systemctl status helloworld
● helloworld.service - Spring Boot HelloWorld
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/helloworld.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-03-13 03:23:21 CET; 6s ago
   Main PID: 1277942 (java)
      Tasks: 41 (limit: 47589)
     Memory: 244.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/helloworld.service
```

Also I have tried with: **teeeest0001.com** instead (since its pointed out in the answer below that example.com is a public/reserved name):

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name teeeest0001.com;

        location / {
             proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        }
}
```

Followed by a `systemctl daemon-reload` but that give a Server not found error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`example.com` is an actual domain, though according to [this rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606#section-3) it is reserved for example use.

If you lookup the DNS record for `example.com` you can see that it resolves to a real IP address, and not to your server:

```sh
~ λ nslookup example.com
Server:     10.50.100.3
Address:    10.50.100.3#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   example.com
Address: 93.184.216.34
```

The easiest way to make what your doing work is simply add an entry to your hosts file to redirect `example.com` to your local server.

The entry would look something like this:

```sh
127.0.0.1 example.com
```

After adding it you would then be able to hit `example.com:8080` and it would hit your dev server. If you want to be able to hit `example.com` without the port you would need to have your dev server listen on port 80, which will require using `sudo` when you run it, which is probably not a good idea. You could also use `socat` or a reverse proxy like [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) or [apache](https://httpd.apache.org/)

It is important to note that this would then only work on the machine on which you modified the hosts file, if you want others to access the site, that is a little outside the scope of this question, but these links may help:

- https://ngrok.com/
- https://serverfault.com/questions/1058/how-do-i-set-up-a-web-server-out-of-my-home (this answer uses a Windows server as an example, but the steps are fundamentally correct)

EDIT:
The issue isn't the reserved nature of `example.com` rather the issue is that your machine does not translate `example.com` or `teeeest0001.com` to your local machine.

The `Server not found error` is due to there not being a DNS record for `teeeest0001.com`.

With regards to what is involved in the connection when using localhost, if you are connecting to port 8080 then you would be bypassing nginx, however if you use port 80, that is where nginx is listening and would then use ProxyPass to connect to the Spring Boot application.

Comment: Not sure I understand. In the above example I am using nginx - running locally on my machine so the whole point is that I should be able to connect to example.com which should hit nginx which then sends to localhost. If I add to /etc/hosts I basically use  another name for locahost meaning nginx does not come into the picture?

Comment: REMOVED, will update answer instead, as question has been updated.